# Is there a way to Update Child Component Data after the Data is changed in Parent Component on regular intervals?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have various child component which are created dynamically in the parent component.

```
RenderFragment CreateChildComponent(long selectedcar) => builder =>
{
    builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(ChildComponent));
    builder.AddAttribute(1, "Data", GetData(selecteccar));
    builder.CloseComponent();
};
```

I have list of data which are passed to these child component.These data is updated in regular intervals at the parent component.

I want to update the child component data when these list gets updated in parent component ?

Comment: Please post some more code. How are you using the results of `RenderFragment CreateChildComponent()`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the kind of scenario depicted in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#manual-rendertreebuilder-logic): Make a property out of the data you passed in to the `CreateChildComponent` method, and then call `StateHasChanged()`. like this:

```
@page "/BuiltContent"

<h1>Build a component</h1>

@CustomRender

@code {
   private RenderFragment CustomRender { get; set; }
   public long selectedcar;

   RenderFragment CreateChildComponent() => builder =>
   {
       builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(ChildComponent));
       builder.AddAttribute(1, "Data", GetData(selectedcar));
       builder.CloseComponent();
   };}

   void SomeInitMethod() {
       childFragment = CreateChildComponent();
   }

   void MyUpdateMethod() {
      // "list gets updated in parent component..."
      this.selectedcar = ...;
      StateHasChanged(); 
   }
}
```